# SwiftUI: Cannot convert value of type '(Task) -> some View' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'

Tags: swiftui

My goal here is to make a SwiftUI struct which makes a scrolling view of data in a sequence, where the data, and the data_view get put together inside the ScrollView.

I get the title error from this code on the ForEach line. The type of the array doesn't seem to matter, I set it to 'Any', and got the same error.

1. If said in an English sentence, what is "(_) -> _"?
   *"A function taking underscore, returning underscore"* doesn't make any sense.
2. What would make this code do what I want?
3. Is this even the best way to do this? 
   (I'm planning on working it to make the code more general, such as making a variable for the view function, but I want to get a working thing before going farther)

```swift
import SwiftUI

protocol DatedOrPrioritizedStruct {
    var id: UUID {get}
    var priority: Float {get set} ///Priority must be set
    var start: Date? {get set} ///Could be nil. Used in conjunction with priority if set.
}

struct TimeLine : View {

    var data: [DatedOrPrioritizedStruct]

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
           NavigationView {
               VStack {
                   ScrollView {
                        ForEach(self.data, id: \.self)  { item in
                                                      //^-ERROR redline here
                            TaskView(task: item).frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: geometry.size.width * 0.80, maxWidth: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                    }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
                     .navigationBarTitle("Do The First Thing", displayMode: .large)
                }
            }.navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
         }
    }
}
```

The Task class:

```swift
public class Task: DatedOrPrioritizedStruct, Identifiable, Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: Task, rhs: Task) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    public let id = UUID()

    var title: String
    var creation: Date
    var priority: Float
    var start: Date?
    var deadline: Date?
    var completed: Date?
    var note: String?
    var recur: Double?
    var duration: TimeInterval


    public init (_ title: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.creation = Date()
        self.priority = 3.0
        self.start = nil
        self.deadline = nil
        self.completed = nil
        self.note = nil
        self.recur = nil
        self.duration = 3600.0
    }

    public init (_ title: String, priority: Float) {
        self.title = title
        self.creation = Date()
        self.priority = priority
        self.start = nil
        self.deadline = nil
        self.completed = nil
        self.note = nil
        self.recur = nil
        self.duration = TimeInterval(9 * 24 * 3600 + 3 * 3600 + 20 * 60)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? Not that it necessarily points to the actual issue since SwiftUI errors rarely do.

Comment: Thanks, it might be very important here.

Comment: I'm guessing from the error that your `Task` class conforms to the `DatedOrPrioritizedStruct` protocol?

Comment: Where the code for `Task`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the

```
TaskView(task: item).frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: geometry.size.width * 0.80, maxWidth: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
```

line with a simple `Text("Testing")`, you'll see the error change to

> Protocol type 'DatedOrPrioritizedStruct' cannot conform to 'Hashable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols

You can fix this by specifying the `ForEach`'s identifier to be `\.id`:

```
ForEach(self.data, id: \.id)  { item in
    TaskView(task: item).frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: geometry.size.width * 0.80, maxWidth: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
}
```

Make sure that `TaskView`'s `task` is of type `DatedOrPrioritizedStruct`, not `Task`, because since your `data` array contains `DataOrPrioritizedStruct` objects, the `item` in the `ForEach` will be a `DataOrPrioritizedStruct`, not a `Task`.

**Side note**: Currently, Xcode often gives irrelevant errors, like in this case, and you can try to figure out the true source by simplifying your code (which I did by putting `Text("Testing")` in the `ForEach` and commenting out the `TaskView` line).

**Edit**:
To clarify, `TaskView` expects to receive `Task` type, but the `ForEach` iterates on an array of `DataOrPrioritizedStruct`, so when you pass `item` into `TaskView` there is no guarantee that the object has the data members that are unique to `Task`, which is why `TaskView`'s `task`'s type must be `DataOrPrioritizedStruct`, not `Task`.

Comment: DatedOrPrioritizedStruct is a protocol, Task conforms.
I changed the id to \.id, and now get "Type '_' has no member 'id'", which is frustrating because it has one.

Comment: Yeah, its not the correct error. The correct error is that You cannot pass a `DataOrPrioritizedStruct` object (`item`) to a view that is expecting a `Task` object (`TaskView`). Like I said in my answer, you have to change `TaskView`'s `task` to be a `DataOrPrioritizedStruct`, not a `Task`. @HackSaw

Comment: Yep, this seems to be the case, which makes me sad. I guess I'll put off generalizing this. Foo.

Comment: Well, it makes sense according to Inheritance principles. The ForEach is iterating a `DataOrPrioritizedStruct`, so the views inside could be passed objects that are not `Task`s. For example, you could create another class called `OtherTask` that conforms to `DataOrPrioritizedStruct` but does not have the duration variable. Since it conforms to `DataOrPrioritizedStruct`, it could be in your `data` array and iterated in the `ForEach`, so you can not pass `OtherTask` to `TaskView`.

Comment: All we know for sure is that variables passed to `TaskView` have and id, priority, and start, because those are the only variables guaranteed by the `DataOrPrioritizedStruct ` protocol.

Comment: Also, if this post answered your question, feel free to accept it!

Comment: Right, so the explicit problem is that TaskView is expecting a Task type, but being offered an object only claiming to conform to DatedOrPrioritizedStruct, which means the type system can't guarantee the item will really be a Task and have a Tasks other data members.

Comment: would you be willing to edit your answer to reflect our discussion here? I fear that a new reader would be confused by the flow.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I mentioned it right above the "Side note", but I'll expand.