# SwiftUI + Realm: removing a row from List results in exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'

Tags: swift, realm, swiftui

I'm trying to port a little RSS feed reader app from UIKit over to SwiftUI, this app uses Realm for persistence.

In order to make Realm bindable in SwiftUI, I added the following code to my project:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift


final class FeedData: ObservableObject {

    @Published var feeds: [Feed] {
        didSet {
            cleanRealm()
        }
    }
    private var feedsToken: NotificationToken?

    private func activateFeedsToken() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let feeds = realm.objects(Feed.self)
        feedsToken = feeds.observe { _ in
            self.feeds = Array(feeds)
        }
    }

    func cleanRealm() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let tempFeeds = realm.objects(Feed.self)
        let diff = feeds.difference(from: tempFeeds)
        for change in diff {
            switch change {
            case .remove(_, let element, _):
                do {
                    try realm.write {
                        print("Removing \(element.name)")
                        if element.isInvalidated {
                            print("Error: element invalidated.")
                        } else {
                            realm.delete(element)
                            print("Removed \(element.name)")
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        feeds = Array(realm.objects(Feed.self))
        activateFeedsToken()
    }

    deinit {
        feedsToken?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

So, we have a feeds array with a DidSet observer that invokes the cleanRealm() function when triggered, which then uses collection diffing to remove Feed objects which are no longer in the array but still stored in Realm - I'm aware this is super clunky, but I figured it would at least keep the array in sync with the Realm database.

In my SwiftUI view, I then use FeedData as EnvironmentObject and use a List showing all Feed objects using ForEach.

When a user deletes a feed from the List, it is then removed from the array like so:

```
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
```

Which then calls this function:

```
func deleteItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    print("Removing feeds at requested offsets.")
    feedData.feeds.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    print("Removed feeds at requested offsets.")
}
```

Problem: when I run my app and then delete an entry from the list, the following exception is thrown:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a4a97ab0 0x1a47b1028 0x10098f6a8 0x100996324 0x1009962e8 0x10000dfa4 0x1b215d830 0x1b215d3f0 0x1b215d170 0x1b215f470 0x1db363c4c 0x1db36a0c8 0x1db36a240 0x1db36a6c0 0x1b22d647c 0x1db3ca2c4 0x1db3c9f04 0x1b21a924c 0x1b21a943c 0x1b21a9b50 0x1b22d647c 0x1daefcd50 0x1db3f0ac4 0x1db3eb7b8 0x1db3ead20 0x1db14dca4 0x1db14c5c0 0x1db4d5d0c 0x1db1bdc1c 0x1db1b836c 0x1db1bef70 0x1cf72c9c0 0x1cf713e9c 0x1cf714164 0x1cf719130 0x1db07f9f0 0x1db084e10 0x1db3ac770 0x1db07f96c 0x1cf719284 0x1db081ca0 0x1db081a48 0x1db0816c8 0x1db081834 0x1db3ac770 0x1db0817fc 0x1db09f848 0x1daf00a10 0x1daf00970 0x1daf00a8c 0x1a4a12668 0x1a4a0d308 0x1a4a0d8b8 0x1a4a0d084 0x1aec56534 0x1a8b7b8b8 0x10004e520 0x1a488ce18)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

My research so far suggests that when a Realm object is deleted, it is mutated before being removed entirely.

So, I think what may be going on here is that when the object is mutated prior to being removed from Realm, SwiftUI detects this change, redraws the view and then tries accessing the now invalidated Realm object resulting in the exception being raised.

Realm objects do have a isInvalidated property that I should probably check before adding it to the List, but AFAIK (and please do feel free to correct me on this) there is no way in a ForEach block to check for such a condition and "continue" to the next array item if desired.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, I've been messing with this issue all day and just cannot find a good solution, it's probably obvious but I'm also still learning about all the wonderful stuff SwiftUI can do while working on this sample project.

Thanks!

Update:

Following Jay's advice, I managed to modify my FeedData class so that it exposes a Realm Results property for my app to work with, instead of copying to a separate array.

That also means I no longer need to do any collection diffing when deleting feeds, but since SwiftUI's .onDelete(perform:) modifier expects a function that accepts an IndexSet, my delete function is still a bit of a hack.

The updated FeedData class now looks as follows:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift


final class FeedData: ObservableObject {

    @Published var feeds: Results<Feed>
    private var feedsToken: NotificationToken?

    private func activateFeedsToken() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let feeds = realm.objects(Feed.self)
        feedsToken = feeds.observe { _ in
            self.feeds = feeds
        }
    }

    func deleteItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        print("deleteItems called.")
        let realm = try! Realm()

        do {
            try realm.write {
                offsets.forEach { index in
                    print("Attempting to access index \(index).")
                    if index < feeds.count {
                        print("Index is valid.")
                        let item = feeds[index]
                        print("Removing \(item.name)")
                        realm.delete(item)
                        print("Removed item.")
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    init() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        feeds = realm.objects(Feed.self)
        activateFeedsToken()
    }

    deinit {
        feedsToken?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

While that technically works, my issue now is that my view's ForEach() method will be called as soon as an object is deleted from the Realm (tested by using breakpoints), this happens even before the Realm notification is dispatched.

This then results in an attempt to access the index of the deleted object, in which case the app will crash with an index out of bounds error from Realm.

That should probably be a separate question though, as my original issue is resolved.

@Jay, can you please mark your first comment as an answer to my question so that I can approve it?

Thanks for the great help!

Comment: Without looking too deeply into the code, I would consider a different approach. Realm objects are live objects - when an object is deleted from Realm, any Results that were aware of that object also has the object removed. By observing those results, the app is notified of the removal and can update the UI accordingly. For example *diffing to remove Feed objects which are no longer in the array* would not be needed as when the objects is deleted from Realm, it would no longer be in the Results. If you're copying results into an Array, you may want use the Results themselves instead.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I fully agree with your opinion that using Realm's Results type directly without the extra step of copying the contained items into an array would be a much better and much more sensible approach. Unfortunately, however, this does not seem to work for whatever reason, Xcode will keep telling me that Feed contains no ID property, although it totally does and I specified it in my ForEach call. I'll try that again and accept your answer if I can pull it off.

Comment: Some things: there's no indication of what ID property is, where it's used or what it has to do with the code in the question. I am not seeing anything using ForEach. Important to remember that when you delete an object from Realm, ALL results that referenced that object would also no longer have that object. So if you delete object at index 4, then try to remove that object it would already be removed and invalid. We don't know what `feedData.feeds.remove` does or what those objects are but that may have something to do with it. If feedData is a results object, that error would be thrown.

Comment: Also, just because Xcode said Feed contains no ID property, it doesn't mean that is the error. It definitely could be true that Feed doesn't contain an ID property for whatever reason, but Xcode in its current state still likes to complain about errors inside of a ForEach by giving unrelated errors that are completely irrelevant to the actual error in the code. See this answer I gave to a different post for an example of what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58372096/5140471

Comment: If you delete a realm object you can't reference it or you will get the exception above.  To avoid this problem use a soft delete by creating a property isDeleted and set this to true and in your query filter using isDeleted.  You run into the same issue if you try and use NSOutlineView because NSOutlineView holds references to the objects and does 'stuff' when you delete the objects that seems to try and reference the realm object.  Alternately use a wrapper class to contain the realm object and then check if the realm object has been invalidated before attempting anything.

Comment: Also in your delete code you should probably copy the items to be deleted to a separate array and then delete them otherwise as soon as you start deleting items from feeds your index references to subsequent objects in feeds will be changed and subsequent iterations will be removing the wrong items or may exceed the bounds of the Results<> set.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem, too. Not sure what's going on, some complicated multiple call behavior caused by SwiftUI, I think. When I expanded my notificationToken observation block and switch on the changes to return if a deletion is called, it works fine. In your case:

```
    feedsToken = feeds.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        switch changes {
        case .initial:
            print("Initial call")
        case .update(_, let deletions, _, _):
            print("Updates made!")
            if !deletions.isEmpty { return }
            self.feeds = feeds
        case .error(let error):
            print("Error observing changes")
        }
    }
```